# Cdf of Multivariate Generalized Gaussian distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis

I would like to generate a sample of random number  based on the multivariate generalized Gaussian distribution, so I need the CDF (cummulative distribution function) for this distribution.
if anyone can help me with the CDF or how to generate random numbers from this distribution.
thanks

Comment: Maybe you should precise what is the multivariate generalized Gaussian distribution (provide a link for example).

Comment: here is an article speaking about the multivariate generalized gaussian distribution to find the pdf of the distribution :                                  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.6498.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To sample from this distribution, you can use the stochastic representation given in section II.B of the paper you linked in your comment.

In R:

```
library(uniformly) # to generate uniform points on the sphere

symMatrixRoot <- function(Sigma){ # calculate a square root of a positive symmetric matrix
  Sigma_eig <- eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE)
  Sigma_eig$vectors %*% (sqrt(Sigma_eig$values) * t(Sigma_eig$vectors))
}

rMGGD <- function(n, m, M, beta){
  p <- nrow(M)
  u <- runif_on_sphere(n, p)
  tau <- (rgamma(n, shape = p/2/beta, rate = 2))^(1/2/beta)
  SigmaRoot <- symMatrixRoot(m*M)
  sims <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = n, ncol = p)
  for(i in 1:n){
    sims[i, ] <- tau[i] * (SigmaRoot %*% u[i, ])
  }
  sims
}

# example 
nsims <- 1000
sims <- rMGGD(nsims, m = 2, M = toeplitz(c(2,1)), beta = 3)
plot(sims[,1], sims[,2])
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Stéphane, it works on matlab too.